# kubectl wait not working for creation of resources

Tags: kubernetes

How do you get around waiting on resources not yes created?

In script I get:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=ready --timeout=60s -n <some namespace> --all pods

error: no matching resources found
```

Comment: Make sure you have provided a valid namespace. I got similar error when the specified namespace was not present.

Comment: Thanks good point, have you see it working using --wait on resources not yet created?

Comment: I don't think it will wait for the resources that hasn't been created yet. Why do you need that?

Comment: I have a script for automating installing/applying and it goes to fast - it works if I do it manually/slow :-)

Comment: Ok. Then, first wait for the resource to get created. Probably a loop running `kubectl get` periodically. When the desired resource is found, break the loop. Then, run `kubectl wait` to wait for the resource to be ready.

Comment: Exactly, thats also what I am thinking :-) Maybe one day: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/83242

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As documented:

> Experimental: Wait for a specific condition on one or many resources.
>
> The command takes multiple resources and waits until the specified
> condition is seen in the Status field of every given resource.
>
> Alternatively, the command can wait for the given set of resources to
> be deleted by providing the "delete" keyword as the value to the --for
> flag.
>
> A successful message will be printed to stdout indicating when the
> specified condition has been met. One can use -o option to change to
> output destination.

This command will not work for the resources that hasn't been created yet. @EmruzHossain has posted two valid points:

- Make sure you have provided a valid namespace.
- First wait for the resource to get created. Probably a loop running `kubectl get` periodically. When the desired resource is found, break the loop. Then, run `kubectl wait` to wait for the resource to be ready.

Also, there is this open thread: [kubectl wait for un-existed resource. #83242](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/83242) which is still waiting (no pun intended) to be implemented.

Answer (score 3):

I found the script here and adjusted it a little bit:
https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/83242#issuecomment-1739443762

```
wait_for_pods_to_exist() {
  local ns=$1
  local pod_name_prefix=$2
  local max_wait_secs=$3
  local interval_secs=2
  local start_time
  start_time=$(date +%s)
  while true; do

    current_time=$(date +%s)
    if (( (current_time - start_time) > max_wait_secs )); then
      echo "Waited for pods in namespace \"$ns\" with name prefix \"$pod_name_prefix\" to exist for $max_wait_secs seconds without luck. Returning with error."
      return 1
    fi

    if kubectl -n "$ns" describe pod "$pod_name_prefix" --request-timeout "5s"  &> /dev/null; then
      echo "Pods in namespace \"$ns\" with name prefix \"$pod_name_prefix\" exist."
      break
    else
      sleep $interval_secs
    fi
  done
}
wait_for_pods_to_exist "namespace" "pod_prefix" 120
```

In addition you can use use:

```
kubectl rollout status -w --namespace namespace deployment/deployment_name --timeout=600s
```

to wait, until the Pod is ready for work.

Comment: If you add -w: kubectl rollout status -w ... then it will wait for the rollout to complete